Fields being overwritten in parent
I have the following query:
await prisma.$kysely
    .selectFrom('Product')
    .selectAll()
    .innerJoin('BrandSupplier', 'Product.brandSupplierId', 'BrandSupplier.id')
    .where(({ or, eb, and }) =>
      or([
        sql<SqlBool>`word_similarity("Product".name, 'heinnekinn') > 0.3`, 
        sql<SqlBool>`word_similarity("BrandSupplier".name, 'heinnekinn') > 0.3`
      ])
    )
    .select((eb) => [
      jsonObjectFrom(
        eb
          .selectFrom('BrandSupplier')
          .selectAll()
          .whereRef('BrandSupplier.id', '=', 'Product.brandSupplierId')
      ).as('brandSupplier')
    ])
    .execute();

The query seems to work but the nested relation (brand supplier) is also being written on top of parent. Here is what I mean:
Expected:
{
  "id": 99999,
  "name": "Heineken 330ml can",
  "sizeMl": 330,
  "brandSupplierId": 22222,
  "brandSupplier": {
    "id": 22222,
    "name": "Heineken brewing co."
  }
}

Actual:
{
  "id": 22222,
  "name": "Heineken brewing co.",
  "sizeMl": 330,
  "brandSupplierId": 22222,
  "brandSupplier": {
    "id": 22222,
    "name": "Heineken brewing co."
  }
}


The problem is the .selectAll().innerJoin('BrandSupplier', 'Product.brandSupplierId', 'BrandSupplier.id') returns overlapping column names (like id and name) in the final result.

Try renaming one of them .select([ 'Product.id as productId',  'Product.name as productName',  'Product.sizeMl',  'Product.brandSupplierId'])   .innerJoin('BrandSupplier', 'Product.brandSupplierId', 'BrandSupplier.id')

The problem is that you are selecting the id column and the name column twice and they end up being stored as a single field. You will need to replace .selectAll() with a .select() which specifies your fields:
.select(
    'Product.id AS pId',
    'Product.name AS pName',
    'Product.sizeMl',
    'Product.brandSupplierId',
)

And do the join like
.innerJoin(
    'BrandSupplier.id AS bsId',
    'BrandSupplier.name AS bsName'
)

Because your function calls will ultimately translate to a query like
SELECT Product.id,
       Product.name,
       Product.sizeMl,
       Product.brandSupplierId,
       BrandSupplier.id,
       BrandSupplier.name
FROM Product
JOIN BrandSupplier
ON Product.brandSupplierId = BrandSupplier.id
...

And since id and name of Product are the same name as their counterparts in BrandSupplier, first Product.id and Product.name are being read and they are overriden by their counterpart in BrandSupplier and by the time the result is being parsed, you have only the second id and name at play to read. So you need to alias them, but beware, the result set will now reference their aliased names.

Hmm so your solution gives the following type error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectExpression<DB, "Product">

@redhouse87 thanks for your comment. It seems that I'm not fluent-enough in the syntax of this ORM, but you can be pretty sure that I'm correct on the idea. I have edited my answer with (hopefully) correct syntax. Please let me know of the test results.

I already commented this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78972916/fields-being-overwritten-in-parent#comment139243177_78972916
